# Dividing listview into columns, with horizontal scroll (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a list view that is divided into two columns. The problem is what happens if the information that comes into the list view is too long of a string.

If I make a fixed width, it will cut some of it. If I make an automatic width, then the initial state of the listview columns will look bad.

Fixed Width:
[image]
Automatic Width:
[image]
Any ideas what can I do to solve this?

relevant XAML:

```
<ListView Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10" Background="#092E3E" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding BackupEvents}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                 ...
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LVTime}"/>

                // auto or fixed?
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"/"520" Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LVDetails}"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The best solution I think would be if I could make the column size fixed, but the text/list-entries to wrap into multiple lines if needed. But I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: Well if you look at Windows Explorer as an example, they cut off the data. Scrolling seems like a weird solution to me... But that's for the people at https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can set a minimum width to a more appealing size `MinWidth=""`

Comment: The workaround I'm using now is to set the column width to Auto, but to place a lot of spaces in the Header, ie " ________  Details ________  ". I find it ugly, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can show ellipsis after certain width of data

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

> The best solution I think would be if I could make the column size fixed, but the text/list-entries to wrap into multiple lines if needed. But I'm not sure how to do that...

You could define an implicit `TextBlock` `Style` that sets the `TextWrapping` property of all `TextBlocks` in the `GridView` to `Wrap`:

```
<ListView Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10" Background="#092E3E" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding BackupEvents}" >
    <!-- HERE: -->
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                ...
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LVTime}"/>

                // auto or fixed?
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"/"520" Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LVDetails}"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: this doesn't work... are you sure my columns content are textblocks?